# Derivative of map $f: S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ is an isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to show that the map $f: S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ given by sending a unit vector $x$ in $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to the line spanned by $x$ in $\mathbb{R}P^n$ has injective derivative.

My attempt so far has been to let $i: S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the inclusion map and $\pi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ be the quotient map and then we can write $f = \pi \circ i$. Using this we have that the derivative is given by: $T_xf = T_x\pi \circ T_xi$. Now in order to show that $T_xf$ is an isomorphism it's sufficient to show it's injective (dimensions match up) so if $v$ is such that $T_xf(v) = 0$ then we have $T_xi(v)$ is in the kernel of $T_x\pi$ but do we know that $T_x\pi$ is injective?

Perhaps there is a simpler way to argue this but I haven't found it. Can we deduce directly that because $f$ is surjective then it's derivative is surjective?

Comment: $T_x \pi$ has no chance to be injective, as the dimension is reduced.

Comment: You have a surjective morphism of smooth manifolds of the same dimension...

Answer (score 0):

We can continue on your way.

Though - as it is remarked, $T_x\pi$ is not injective - we can figure out its kernel: 
By dimension considerations, it is one dimensional, and as moving align on the line of vector $x$ (and the origin) in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, its image is staying in one point, hence (after identifying $T_x\Bbb R^{n+1}=\Bbb R^{n+1}$), $x$ itself will generate the kernel. 
However, $x$ is orthogonal to the tangent hyperplane of the sphere $im\, T_xi$, in particular, $x\perp v$, which together proves that $v=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we know that the kernel of $T_x \pi$ is one-dimensional? It maps an n+1 dim. space to an n dim. space but we don't know it is surjective? Are you using the fact that a surjective map has a surjective derivative (if that's true!)? In which case wouldn't that be a direct proof of the original question anyway? Thanks

Comment: $T_x\pi$ and $\Bbb RP^n$ are very concrete: if you choose appropriate coordinate systems, you can write it as the orthogonal projection matrix to a hyperspace. By the way,your claim about surjective maps seems plausible enough, however, I just could not manage to rigorously prove it..

Comment: @Berci No, the claim about surjective maps is not true. For example $x \to x^3$  is clearly surjective as a map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, but it's differential at $x = 0$ is not surjective. By the way, a map whose differential is surjective everywhere is called submersion.